# Conditional sum on data.frame based on duplicates

Tags: mysql, r, finance

I have been trying to make a conditional sum based on a `data.frame`that has duplicates. I want to sum the ones that has an identical permno and date and create a separate column with this information filling in NA's or preferable 0's.

My data set looks like this:

```
data.frame(crsp)

    permno     date    PAYDT DISTCD divamt FACPR FACSHR   PRC       RET
1   10022 19280929 19281001   1272   0.25     0      0 71.00  0.045208
2   10022 19280929 19281001   1232   1.00     0      0 71.00  0.045208
3   10022 19281031       NA     NA     NA    NA     NA 73.50  0.035211
4   10022 19281130       NA     NA     NA    NA     NA 72.50 -0.013605
5   10022 19281231 19290202   1232   1.00     0      0 68.00 -0.044828
6   10022 19281231 19290202   1272   0.25     0      0 68.00 -0.044828
7   10022 19290131       NA     NA     NA    NA     NA 73.75  0.084559
8   10022 19290228       NA     NA     NA    NA     NA 69.00 -0.064407
9   10022 19290328 19290401   1232   1.00     0      0 65.00 -0.039855
10  10022 19290328 19290401   1272   0.25     0      0 65.00 -0.039855
11  10022 19290430       NA     NA     NA    NA     NA 67.00  0.030769
12  10022 19290531       NA     NA     NA    NA     NA 64.75 -0.033582
```

First, I have created permno + date to make a unique pickup-code

```
crsp$permnodate = paste(as.character(crsp$permno),as.character(crsp$date),sep="")
```

Second, I have then tried to sum the duplicates and making this into a new frame:

```
crsp_divsingl <- aggregate(crsp$divamt, by = list(permnodate = crsp$permnodate), FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, I am unable to transfer this information back correctly to the original `data.frame(crsp)`, as the columns have different lenghts where `cbind` and `cbind.fill` don't allow me to match this correctly. Specifically, I want the sum of the divamts for one/the first of the unique permnodates so it corresponds with the remaining `data.frame` in length. I have not had succed with `merge` or `match` either.

I haven't tried loop functions yet or managed to create any `if` or `ifelse` functions with succes. Basically, this can be done in excel with the VLOOKUP or the index.match formula, however, this is more tricky in R than I first thought.

Help is much appreciated.

Best regards

Troels

Comment: You can use `duplicated` to do this. I'm writing an answer below, but one questions, when you say, "create a separate column with this information filling in NA's or preferable 0's.", do you mean that you want to convert NA values in the data to 0's?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment!
 I  am using the `duplicated` function for making a separate `data.frame` just for individual prices (another part of the data set I am trying to replicate). 

So, because there are multiple permnodates, and I want to have one sum for these duplicates, the other rows in the new column, where the duplicates are, needs to carry either the same value as the first permnodate or alternatively be a 0 or NA. Otherwise, the separate column will have a different length than the other columns in the sheet.
I hope it makes sense.
I will try your answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff. Let me know if there's anything else I can help with.

Comment: I have just tried playing around with your code below - which unfortunately was not successful. Is there any way I can have a chat with you on skype etc. to elaborate on what I am trying to do in the data set? Thanks!

Comment: My time is pretty limited unfortunately, but you can make an edit in your question to try and put into more detail when you're trying to do. I think you have it, but you've run into some formatting difficulty. Remember to think about what it means to line up the sums in the new column. How do you want to line them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` and `merge` to achieve this more easily. I've written an example. You'll have to alter this for your purposes, but hopefully it will put you on the right track:

```
# Creating a fake sample dataset.
set.seed(9)
permno <- 10022:10071 # Allowing 50 possible permno's. 
date <- 19280929:19280978 # Allow 50 possible dates.
value <- c(NA, 1:9) # Allowing NA or a 0 through 9 value.

# Creating fake data frame.
crsp <- data.frame(permno = sample(permno, 1000, TRUE), date = sample(date, 1000, TRUE), value = sample(value, 1000, TRUE))

# Loading a function that uses duplicated to get both the duplicated rows and the original rows.
fullDup <- function(x) {

  bool <- duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)
  return(bool)

}

# Getting the duplicated rows.
crsp.dup <- crsp[fullDup(crsp[, c("permno", "date")]), ] # fullDup returns a boolean of all the rows that were duplicated to another row by permno and date including the first row.

# Now aggregate.
crsp.dup[is.na(crsp.dup)] <- 0 # Converting NA values to 0.
crsp.dup <- aggregate(value ~ permno + date, crsp.dup, sum)
names(crsp.dup)[3] <- "value.dup" # Changing the name of the value column.

# Now merge back in with the original dataset.
crsp <- merge(crsp, crsp.dup, by = c("permno", "date"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by using below line in the dplyr package:
crsp <- full_join(crsp_divsingl, crsp, by = "permnodate")
It seems to have done the job.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds good. As a note, a `full_join` should be equivalent to a `merge` with the argument `all = TRUE`.